# Google Closure Compiler: cost of obfuscation/CompilationOption

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

The Class CompilationOption is used to control the compilation pass. In the build-in "optimize" options(such as foldConstants, removeDeadcode etc), closure compiler only activates some of them by default. So why not enable all of them? Will that generate more obfuscated codes or not? What is the cost of enabling a new option?

Thanks, any insight would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There are passes in the compiler which are:

- deprecated and no longer used
- only applicable in specific environments (alias strings if you don't have gzip)
- Are very intensive during compilation and offer very little size or performance benefit.

The default options are set per compilation level and are a balance between performance, compiled size and compilation time.

We generally don't recommend turning on the other passes unless you have a specific need.